# SwiftUI - background processing in a view

Tags: ios, swift, background-process

I have a music player that needs to fetch the current song from a function over and over again.

up til now I have put the function inside the view (SwiftUI) using the function `.onAppear{}` while technically it worked I found that when a user clicks on the view to make it bigger, or even when they close and reopen the app from background mode it is re-running the code as if it has not already started.

So I thought by adding a  `self.timer?.invalidate()` function  `@State var timer: Timer?`

I could potentially allow the script to run while it's open and then stop it when it disappears, that worked all the way up to when I needed to add

```
 .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification), perform: { output in
            self.timer?.invalidate()
        })
```

The issue now is when I reopen the app it won't restart - not sure why.

But I am starting to feel that there must be a better way to do this function, after all it's only checking a function that is in another file on loop.

So my question: where is the best place to create a code that does this

```
 Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5, repeats: true) { timer in 
   //CODE HERE
}
```

Clearly it needs to run once and in the background but not be called again unless the app is opened for the first time.

I was thinking I need to put it inside the AppDelegate file because I know that file is called only once or when certain functions need to run.

I was thinking this section

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
//INSERT CODE HEER

}
```

I know that I would then need to just store the values to something like
`UserDefaults.standard.set`

and then just get the MediaPlayerView.swift to refresh these values.

Is this the best practice and what others would recommend?, And am I right by saying a view should only be reading information not trying to run functions.

Comment: [How to use a timer with SwiftUI](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-a-timer-with-swiftui)

Comment: @MadProgrammer mmm I think this is different when your running a function inside the timer as I am - I could be wrong? What is the .autoconnect() part?

Also my problem is not the timer it's the fact it's was running multiple timers instead of one timer, so I made some changes and now it's not restarting the timer when I close the app to background mode and re-open it.

Comment: I set one up to be refresh an api call every 30 seconds, which seems to work okay, but I’ve only just started playing with it

Comment: Your view shouldn't be pulling anything using a timer. You should have a model that is publishing whatever properties your view needs. Your model may use a timer to publish the property

Comment: @Paulw11 I agree 100% with you but where do I call the model from if it needs to run in the background - as the iOS media player needs to read it

Comment: You don't "call" the model.  You can inject it to the SwiftUI environment or you can create an instance using `@StateObject`.  The model can the use `@Published` properties to update the view